# Qt5Gui.dll 32-bit architecture mismatch

Tags: c++, qt

I have developed an application in 64-bit Windows. When i was trying to run the application there were some missing files(Qt5Widgets.dll,Qt5Gui.dll) i replaced these files in the folder. But Qt5Gui.dll was a 32-bit version. Now it is throwing an error which mean that Qt5Gui.dll is a 32-bit.

Is there any alternatice solution for this? Or can i get a 64-bit version of Qt5Gui.dll?

Please help. [image]

Comment: just download and install the 64 bit version of QT.

Comment: I am using 64-bit version of Qt.

Comment: Do  you have only 1 version of QT installed on your machine? Have you tried to use windeployqt.exe "your application" it should be located in the bin folder of your QT installation. see if that works. Are you using MinGW or visual studio?

Comment: Do you have Qt5Gui.dll in your Qt installation bin folder? Does *missing* mean, you don't have the dll file in your system, or just the application can't find the dll file?

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez i have only one version of qt application. You mean i need place the release folder in bin folder of Qt installation directory? I am using MinGW.

Comment: open the command prompt and cd to the bin directory of your qt installation. then run windeployqt.exe with the additional parameter of your executable file. see if it copies the neccessary dlls to your executable folder.

Comment: @rafeal that worked!! Thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run the following command in the command prompt which will fetch all the missing .dll/library files to the application executable.

C:\Qt\Qt5.6.2\5.6\msvc2015_64\bin>windeployqt.exe

It worked for me. Hope it works.
[image: libs got added]
Thanks rafeal.